# How can I increase baselineskip in a document using memoir class?

Tags: memoir, line-spacing

I am trying to increase the baselineskip for every chapter except the titlepage. I am using setlength to change its value but it has no effect. Any help would be great. Following is my main file.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{memoir}

% \includeonly{./chapters/conclusion/conclusion}

\usepackage{graphicx} % For inserting graphics in the page
\usepackage{epstopdf} % For automatically converting eps images to pdf while using pdflatex
\usepackage{dblfloatfix} % For using a "b" as placement specifier for a page wide image
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % For ensuring correct image numbering when we use \figure*
\usepackage{mathtools} % For using mathematics environments
\usepackage{amsfonts} % For using text formatting in equations eg \mathbf
\usepackage{algorithm} % For wrapping algorithmic environment to produce a floating    environment.
\usepackage{algorithmic} % For using algorithmic environment
\usepackage{threeparttable} % For adding footnotes to the table
\usepackage{subcaption} % For putting multiple figures within a single figure environment
\usepackage{tikz} % For drawing

\graphicspath{{chapters/SASNN/img/}{chapters/GSNN/img/}{chapters/literature/img/}{chapters/intro/img/}{chapters/conclusion/img/}{garnish/cover/}}

\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}

% To ensure equal margin for odd and even pages
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{15.5pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{15.5pt}

% Increase line spacing
\setlength{\baselineskip}{24pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}

\begin{document}
% title page
\input{./garnish/cover/cover}

% abstract
\begin{abstract}
\input{./garnish/abstract/abstract} % We use input because usage of include causes an extra bank page to be added.
\end{abstract}

\mainmatter    
\include{./chapters/intro/intro}
\include{./chapters/literature/literature}
\include{./chapters/GSNN/gsnn}
\include{./chapters/SASNN/sasnn}
\include{./chapters/conclusion/conclusion}

\backmatter
\include{./garnish/pub/pub}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{../../../Bibliography/Bibtex/SNN}
\end{document}
```

UPDATE: I tried  \linespread also but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Thanks for replying.......Moving $\setlength{\baselineskip}{24pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}$ to after \mainmatter worked for me....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of `memoir`'s own spacing commands (based on `setspace`) is my recommendation since it doesn't doublespace things that really shouldn't be doublespaced, and doesn't suffer from the above `\baselineskip` change, which won't work as soon as a font size change is made.  See this [FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-linespace).
Compare the following example:

```
\documentclass[openany, 11pt, a4paper, twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\DoubleSpacing%             <-- memoir command; comment and this line and uncomment the next...
\setlength{\baselineskip}{24pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}% <-- ... in order to see the difference

\mainmatter
\chapter{a}

\footnote{\lipsum*[2]}%
\large %                   <-- things like this will cause problems (and they are often implicitly set by other document commands)
\lipsum[1]

\backmatter

\chapter{b}\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

`memoir` in fact offers a whole suite of spacing commands; consult the manual (§ 3.3.2) for the many options.